# Draw a shaded wheel in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a shaded wheel using Tikz

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \shade[outer color=gray,middle color=gray!10,inner color=gray] [even odd rule] (0,0) circle (1.5) (0,0) circle (1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `middle color` wont work ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get a precise radial shading, you must take into account the following extract and the pictures from p.1086 of pgfmanual (v3.0.1a):

> *The shading is scaled and translated such that the point (50bp, 50bp),
>   which is the middle of the shading, is at the middle of the path and
>   such that the point (25bp, 25bp) is at the lower left corner of the
>   path and that (75bp, 75bp) is at upper right corner.*

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{gray ring}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}%
{
  color(0bp)=(gray);
  color(16.66666bp)=(gray); % = 1/1.5 * 25bp
  color(20.83333bp)=(gray!10); % = 1.25/1.5 * 25bp
  color(25bp)=(gray);
  color(50bp)=(gray)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade[even odd rule,shading=gray ring]
  (0,0) circle (1.5) circle(1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can define a new shading, e.g., `\pgfdeclareradialshading{ring}`, like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{ring}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}%
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(.6666cm)=(.6,.5,.5);
rgb(1cm)=(1,1,1)}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[shading=ring, even odd rule] (0,0) circle (1.5) circle (1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just add a draw command for the inner circle:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \shade[outer color=gray,middle color=red,inner color=gray] [even odd rule] (0,0) circle (1.5) (0,0) circle (1);
       \draw[fill=blue!50, radius=1.5,draw=gray] (0,0) circle (1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have added `draw=gray` so that the colour of the border to the inner circle matches the shaded region.

[image]

**EDIT**

I suspect that this is ot what you want, but the `middle color` is being overridden by the `inner color=gray` thar follows it. You need to put `middle color` last in order for it to work. The code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \shade[outer color=gray,inner color=gray, middle color=gray!10, even odd rule](0,0) circle (1.5) circle (1.25);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I think that you need AboAmmar's approach!

Comment: What I want is something like a cylindrical shad inside the region that I already draw.

Comment: What do you mean by a "cylindrical shade". You want a gradient?